# Firestore Rule allowing overwrite

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a users collection where each document contains a name field and and an access map.

```
"users" :[
   {
     "mHbVq5TUY7brlleejClKm71NBGI2": {
         "name": "Bob Johnson",
         "access": {
             "X0w1VaVIljR1Nc5u3Sbo" : true
         }
   }
]
```

I would like the Firestore rules to allow creation of a new document only if it doesn't already exist and only if the person performing the action has had their email verified. For the update, only the user owning that node can perform the update, the name must be a string, and the access map should not be able to be changed. I tested my update and create rules in the simulator and they worked as expected. However, when I run a .set() it completely overwrites my entire node and removes the access map which I cannot have happen. I assume that a .set() is actually performing an update and thus meeting my update criteria. So, how do I prevent someone from completely overwriting my node. Thanks in advance...code below.

---CODE PERFORMING OVERWRITE

```
db.collection("users").doc("mHbVq5TUY7brlleejClKm71NBGI2").set(
  {
    name: "Bill Swanson",
  }
).catch(err => {
  console.log(err.message)
})
```

---RULES

```
function incomingData() {
  return request.resource.data
}

function emailVerified() {
  return request.auth.token.email_verified;
}

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {

      function userExists(user_Id) {
        return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(user_Id));
      }

        allow create: if !userExists(userId) && emailVerified();
        allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId
                      && !('access' in incomingData())
                      && request.resource.data.name is string;
         allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: According to this link (https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.17.x/DocumentReference#set) the .set does actually perform an update if the document already exists but it is obviously ignoring my update rule and overwriting the entire document instead of merging. Would love to know if someone has a workaround for this? I have seen a lot of examples using this approach to prevent overwriting and it seems they would have similar results (https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/f18b1991f74f7a266e0d15f31d46d637)

Comment: After spinning my wheels I discovered a very subtle distinction in the documentation  (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions). "For update operations that only modify a subset of the document fields, the request.resource variable will contain the pending document state after the operation." So when I am doing my comparison of incomingData to existingData its really not the incomingData. Why aren't more of the experts drawing this distinction? This type of question is all over the place and the experts say that the request.resource.data is the data being sent in?

Comment: The only true way to get the actual incomingData from the request is to look at the request.writeFields which is being deprecated and can't be used on the simulator. I would actually write up an entire post on my experiences in tracking this down but evidently I cant initiate any new questions because I am being limited. Not sure exactly why that is. I also can't go answer the myriad of questions just like mine because I don't have reputation points. Well, I sure wish some of those that do would go answer these questions. People are being led astray by bad advice and demos.

Answer (score 1):

When using set(), If you're not sure whether the document exists, pass the option to merge the new data with any existing document to avoid overwriting entire documents.

Here's how to pass the option to merge the update with the existing document.

```
db.collection("users")
.doc("mHbVq5TUY7brlleejClKm71NBGI2")
.set(
   {
      name: "Bill Swanson"
   },
   {
      merge: true
   }
).catch(err => {
   console.log(err.message)
});
```

Hope this helps.