# Delete collection firestore:go

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I took a data set of 10 collections from api xyz, then updated it to firebase for the first time.

On the second update, api xyz has 9 collections available, How to make the 2nd update with only 9 collections (the existing ones being overwritten and the extra collections from the first update should be deleted)?

I used to delete all the collections and then update but that method is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

For you to perform bulk updates on your collections, you need to use 
[Transactions and Batched Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) - as I imagine that you are already using to perform the update in the first time.

If you just want to overwrite the old date, you need to configure a `set()` method just to update the collection, without needing to check the existence of any document on it. This way, it should overwrite the data already existed. You can get more information on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982693/firestore-rule-allowing-overwrite), where a customer describes the function that he is using that is overwriting data.

Let me know if the information helped you!